# Digitizing on raster WMTS time series and storing time information in attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, time-series, timeslider, temporal-controller

I have loaded a raster time series in QGIS as a WMTS layer. The Temporal Controller works fine and I can navigate through the different dates.

Now, I would like to digitize polygons on different time steps (for instance to map fires). All these features would be in a single file (shapefile or equivalent) and I would like the time of the image to be stored as an attribute.

Is it possible?

Comment: It seems like this is currently not an option, the attribute form doesn't have access to either the @animation_* or @frame_* variables so you currently can't use them to update your vector layer.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51105) regarding this, hopefully it can be a quick solve.